# SVN export to working directory

Tags: svn, version-control

we have to following problem. If we export your changes to our development sever the export will not delete any files on the server. And for good reasons we do not want to do this manually. So I thought about to make the directory on the server as working copy to but so any developer has to submit his changes to the repository just for testing his changes. I think this is very unpractical and will make many revision who are not necessary.

So we need the best from both world - so is SVN have the ability to handle it if we export our changes to the working directory for testing and afterward to update of the working directory after our development is finished.

Regards,
Marcel

Answer (score 0):

> If we export your changes to our development sever the export will not delete any files on the server.

Your deployment script should simply delete the previously exported folder and create a fresh export. Surely a few seconds of downtime is not a problem for a development server?

If the downtime *is* a problem (e.g. your project is very large and it takes a long time for the export to complete) then you can still deploy the next revision instantly by making use of hard links or symbolic links.

For example, you could host your project in `/var/www/myproject.latest` which is actually a hard link to `/var/www/myproject.r123`. After a new revision `124` is exported, you instantly update the hardlink with this command:

```
ln -f /var/www/myproject.r124 /var/www/myproject.latest
```

(I have assumed that your project is hosted on a linux server, but you can also use [NTFS junction][1] points on Windows.)

> So I thought about to make the directory on the server as working copy to but so any developer has to submit his changes to the repository just for testing his changes.

`svn export` has the same restriction, so I don't see how both approaches differ in this regard. If all developers need to share the same test server, then this is a good thing in any case: if developer A breaks the test server, then developer B wants to be able to look at the SVN log to see what happened!